# SharePoint 2016 running PSConfig

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, patching

Below article explained how to patch SP 2016 with Zero Downtime patching(ZDP). In this article the product config initially running on  web front end server(WFE) rather.Why the WFE is prepared over Apps servers?

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/upgrade-and-update/sharepoint-server-2016-zero-downtime-patching-steps

Is there any advantage running WFE server ahead of Apps servers?

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific order in which you need to run the psconfig tool, either in general or to follow ZDP.

Comment: Thanks for replying my query.Is there any best practice to patch  Search service application with ZDP implementation.